# Is XForms able to define multi-part forms in which a user can move forward and backward, and which can contain logic to display or hide sections?

Tags: xforms

Is XForms able to define multi-part forms in which a user can move forward and backward, and which can contain logic to display or hide sections?  Or is this beyond the scope of what XForms is meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with including all your sub-forms within as single enclosing XForms document, then you can do this today (with XForms 1.1): the navigation between sub-forms can be implemented with an enclosing `xforms:switch` and appropriate buttons and actions to determine when to show or hide a given sub-form.

So the answer is "yes" it is possible, and "no" it is not beyond the scope of XForms.

As Alain mentions in his reply, XForms 2 plans to support dynamic sub-form loading. See [some work in progress](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0#The_load_Element).

Answer (score 0):

XForms 2.0 Specifications will define a sub-form mechanism. This is not fully described yet but betterform and XSLTForms already implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an important feature especially when the form takes a long time to load.  I created a technique I called "Incremental Model Loading" that will only load the data for one tab at a time.  If you only are changing items on the first tab the other tabs will never need to load.

I put the example here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Incremental_Model_Loading

Note that all the UI elements load when the pages load, but the complex binding rules, which take up a lot of the load times, are not loaded.